# How to make my c# form work with oracle for others?

Tags: c#, oracle, tnsnames, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have scoured StackOverflow far and wide for an answer to this question, but nothing seemed to help me so I'll ask it here now:

So, I have a rather simple form with a few labels & fields and a button.

Once you click on the button, you perform a query on a DB. The result gets displayed across several fields. When I run the program for myself, at work, using F5 in Visual Studio 2013, the form works flawlessly, using the reference Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

**However, when I run the program on another PC at work (same network and all), the program returns an oracle “ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified”-error.**

What you should know: I set up the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess so that it uses the standard TNSNames.ora file located at c:\Oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\ADMIN.
This location is the same for every PC on the network, at work. However, the TNSNames.ora file is not always as complete as me, I might have a couple more connections available than others. That's why, as you'll see in my code soon, I basically say: "if SID xxxxx is found in document X at location Y, do nothing, else, add the necessary connection info specified here: ..."

Here's the code I use that concerns all the connections. For privacy reasons I replaced the connection details with fake names, and translated some of the things from Dutch into English, for your better understanding.

As the code is very long, I'm only showing the part about the connection, and I'm leaving everything else out. But as I said before, the complete code works, only... just for me. I'd like to make it work for everyone else at work.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Data;    
using System.Linq;   
using System.Windows.Formss    
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class GetLivingWagesV2 : Form
    {
        public GetLivingWagesV2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PLEASE SELECT AN ENVIRONMENT FIRST.");
            }

            var objtextbox = textBox1.Text;

            var ConnectionString350 = "DATA SOURCE=DATABASEPREREGRESSION01;PASSWORD=test;USER ID=REGGY";

            var ConnectionString300 = "DATA SOURCE=DATABASEREGRESSION01;PASSWORD=test;USER ID=REGGY";

            var Connection = new OracleConnection();

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                var PEN300 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora").Contains("PENREG.RSVZINASTI.BE") ? 1 : 0;

                Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString300;

                Connection.Open();

                var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(b.msg_flux_in, 4000, 200) AS MSG_FLUX_IN, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(b.msg_flux_out, 4000, 200) AS MSG_FLUX_OUT FROM tb2b_flux a, tb2b_flux_status b where a.flux_svf_id = '" + objtextbox + "' and a.flux_id = b.flux_id order by a.dt_creatie desc";

                var Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                var dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Load(Reader);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                var column = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
                column.Width = 380;

                var column1 = dataGridView1.Columns[1];
                column1.Width = 380;

                if (PEN300 == 0)
                {
                    using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora", true))
                    {
                        file.WriteLine("DATABASEREGRESSION.ORGANISATION.BE =");
                        file.WriteLine("  (DESCRIPTION =");
                        file.WriteLine("    (ADDRESS_LIST =");
                        file.WriteLine("      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = unxin600)(PORT = 1522))");

                        file.WriteLine("    )");
                        file.WriteLine("    (CONNECT_DATA =");
                        file.WriteLine("      (SID = DATABASEREGRESSION01)");
                        file.WriteLine("    )");
                        file.WriteLine("  )");
                    }
                }
            }


            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                var PEN350 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora").Contains("pendvt01.rsvzinasti.be") ? 1 : 0;

                if (PEN350 == 0)
                {
                    using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora", true))
                    {
                        file.WriteLine("DATABASEPREREGRESSION =");
                        file.WriteLine("  (DESCRIPTION =");
                        file.WriteLine("    (ADDRESS_LIST =");
                        file.WriteLine("      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = UNXPR651)(PORT = 1522))");

                        file.WriteLine("    )");
                        file.WriteLine("    (CONNECT_DATA =");
                        file.WriteLine("      (SERVICE_NAME =DATABASEPREREGRESSION01)");
                        file.WriteLine("    )");
                        file.WriteLine("  )");
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString350;

                    Connection.Open();

                    var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(b.msg_flux_in, 4000, 200) AS MSG_FLUX_IN, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(b.msg_flux_out, 4000, 200) AS MSG_FLUX_OUT FROM tb2b_flux a, tb2b_flux_status b where a.flux_svf_id = '" + objtextbox + "' and a.flux_id = b.flux_id order by a.dt_creatie desc";

                    var Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                    var dt = new DataTable();

                    dt.Load(Reader);

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                    var column = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
                    column.Width = 380;

                    var column1 = dataGridView1.Columns[1];
                    column1.Width = 380;
                }
            }    

            if (Connection != null && Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Connection.Open();
            }

            else
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }



            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells)
                {
                    if (dc.Value == null || dc.Value.ToString().Trim() == string.Empty)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count < 2)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("De FluxID werd niet gevonden.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post your code in a question, don't post all your code. Just the minimum amount required to recreate your error. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do you know that file `tnsnames.ora` is **always** stored at `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\ADMIN`? Oracle.ManagedDataAccess determines location of `tnsnames.ora` automatically, see here: https://community.oracle.com/message/10610812#10610812

Answer (score 2):

The `tnsnames.ora` file is probably not used, because the connection string uses EZ CONNECT (easy connect) format. Try modifying the data source inside the connectionstring:

```
DATA SOURCE=HOSTNAME:1521/DATABASENAME;PASSWORD=...;USER ID=...
```

Trying to do without `tnsnames.ora` would make sense for a Windows Forms application, because it would make distribution and application support easier. No need to take care of this file, which is just an external element not under your control that needs to be handled, its installation and updates, it probably means also needing to parse the file to make an update of it, it can be changed by accident by another user or by another application. A single line connection string in a configuration file of the application is less trouble.

An overview of connection string formats for the ODP.NET provider are here:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/

Comment: I'm not a c# programmer, but ...  1) it's never a good idea to hard code locations, etc. in a program.  Can't adjust to changing realities.(like running on different systems). 2) your ora-12514 means exactly what it says.  It is trying to resolve a tns name reference in the specific client's tnsnames.ora and can't find it.  You need to check tnsnames.ora on the specific client AND sqlnet.ora on the specific client.  Pay attention to names.default_domain in sqlnet.ora.  I've written extensively about ora-12154 at http://edstevensdba.com/oracle-tns/ora-12154tns-03505/

Comment: I don't see any EZ CONNECT in provided code, the connection does not use any EZ CONNECT.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit You are right the format is not EZ CONNECT or not fully, it does not contain user name nad password inside the data source key which the EZ format does. The ODP.NET provider can understand also this mixed format.

Comment: @EdStevens i can see your points, still i would prefer to try to do without this file in windows forms application, added the reasons to the answer.

Comment: It depends. If you have stuff like `FAILOVER` or `LOAD_BALANCE` you cannot use EZ CONNECT. In bigger organizations the connect string may be provided by an LDAP server. For example, in my company our IT runs around 300 Oracle databases and EZ CONNECT would not be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend placing your server info inside of your `web/app.config`. That way, clients don't even need to have a `tnsnames.ora` file, or even have ever installed oracle.

Here's the sections you may need to add to your `web/app.config` files to get it to work. I usually suffix the connection names with `.managed` to ensure there are no naming conflicts (in theory, the client should look in `web/app.config` before going to `tnsnames.ora`, but I don't trust oracle and this makes it super explicit  :)

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DbContext" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=XXXXX.managed;USER ID=XXXXX;PASSWORD=XXXXXXX;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;POOLING=False" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

    <!-- add this if you use Entity Framework only -->
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <!-- here's the important bit, just copy descriptor from your existing tnsnames.ora file -->
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
            <dataSources>
                <dataSource alias="XXXXX.managed" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXXXX.com)(PORT = 999999))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XXXXX)(SERVER = dedicated)))" />
            </dataSources>
        </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

after that, you can change your code to use the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` (or equivalent depending on version) instead of hard-coding the string into your code (because that's generally a bad practice).

Comment: If the application prompts the user to select an environment (i.e. a database) then you don't need any config file. It will be provided by the user.